# How do I change the size of a diode in Circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

I want to reduce the size of the diode D1 in my circuit, but I can't seem to be able to do that using \ctikzset{diode/scale=0.5} as it gives an error wherever in the document I place it. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{diode/scale=0.5}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
    to[V,v=$V$, invert] (0,7)   
    to [short, -o] ++(2,0)
    to[cC, l_=$C_i$] (2,0)
    to[short, -o] (0,0);
\draw (2,7)
    to [short] ++(2,0)
    to [V, v=$fet$] ++(0,-3)
    to [full diode, l_=$D_1$, invert] ++(0, -4)
    to [short, -o] ++(-2,0);  
\draw (4, 3.5)
    to [L, l_=$L_0$] ++(3,0)
    to [cC, l_=$C_0$] ++(0,-3.5)
    to [short, -o] ++(-3, 0);
\draw (7, 3.5)
    to [short] ++(1.5,0)
    to [R, v=$R_0$] ++(0,-3.5)
    to [short] ++(-1.5,0);
\draw
    [-latex] (5,4) -- (6,4);
\draw
    [-latex] (7.25,4) -- (8.25,4);
\draw
    (5.5, 4.25) node{$i_{Lo}$}
    (7.75, 4.25) node{$i_{o}$};
    
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look nearer :

[image]

The class is `diodes` (plural), so `\ctikzset{diodes/scale=0.5}`...